# Cannot access video file in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use cvCreateFileCapture with android but it returns null. I think it's how I'm using it. phn_med0083_n062 is a .avi in raw directory.

```
InputStream file = (context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.phn_med0083_n062));

cvCapture2 = cvCreateFileCapture(file.toString());
```

Apparently `file.toString()` is not giving the path of the video file `phn_med0083_n062.avi`, so how can I get it?

Comment: What is the value of `file.toString()`?

Comment: android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream@2203d998

Comment: That doesn't seem to be like a video file name, does it?

Comment: No ... I don't know why

Comment: Do you know how to access files in raw?

Comment: something like this: `String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;`

Comment: It doesn't work either.

Comment: Dude, come on cooperate a little bit... What is the value? Try just using the `R.raw.video_file` alone...

Comment: android.resource://com.clintonmedbery.myproject/2131099657

I try using only R.raw too.

Comment: What is the file name? Is it 2131099657.avi? if yes, just put ".avi" at the end. Go check it from the file system if the path is correct.

Comment: No the name is phn_med0083_n062.avi

Comment: I can't help you.. Please go read some documentation or SO questions about accessing files in android. Your problem is about the file path, this is not an OpenCV or Android-Studio question...

Comment: ok thank you for your time